# Numpy.where() with an array in its conditional

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I don't know how to describe this well so I'll just show it.

How do I do this...

```
for iy in random_y:
    print(x[np.where(y == iy)], iy)

  X        y
[ 0.5] :   0.247403959255
[ 2.]  :   0.841470984808
[ 49.5]:  -0.373464754784
```

without for loops and I get a solution as a single array like when you use `np.where()` or `array[cond]`. Since you know, this is Python B)

**NOTE:** The reason why I want to do this is because I have a random subset of the Y values and I want to find the corresponding X values.

Comment: Are the values in `y` unique?

Comment: yes each of the y values are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for exact matches, you can simply use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) as this is a perfect scenario for its usage, like so -

```
first_output = x[np.in1d(y,random_y)]
second_output = random_y[np.in1d(random_y,y)
```

---

If you are dealing with floating-point numbers, you might want to use some tolerance factor into the comparisons. So, for such cases, you can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and then use `np.where`, like so -

```
tol = 1e-5 # Edit this to change tolerance
R,C = np.where(np.abs(random_y[:,None] - y)<=tol)

first_output = x[C]
second_output = random_y[R]
```

Comment: Looks great, testing this now. Does this or a similar method generalize to 2d arrays? (PS: I wish I could double thumb up thing!)

Comment: @SARose So, for 2D arrays, you need to decide if by "==" do you mean all elements in a row or any one element in a row, assuming you would like a row based comparison. If you are really looking to extend this to 2D, it might be a good idea to post a sample case in the question or post a new question altogether, because it won't be a straight forward extension.

Comment: Okay I'll post a sample case. But yeah I do want all the elements in one row from one array to match all the elements in one row from another array.

Comment: @SARose So, a quick way with broadcasting for 2D case, would be : `R,C = np.where((random_y[:,None] == y).all(2))`. Then `x[C]` and `random_y[R]` would be the outputs just as listed for `1D` solution. Not a great deal of change there! :)

Comment: @SARose Likewise for tolerance, you can use `R,C = np.where((np.abs(random_y[:,None] - y) <= tol).all(2))` keeping rest the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do the trick(not tested):

`print(Str(x[np.where(y == iy)]) + " " + Str(iy) + "\n") for iy in random_y`